# Dynamical creating dropdown from database data in PHP & Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make dynamical dropdown that will be populated by data collected from database. I am stuck at parsing data from multidimensional array sent by PHP file. My code:

Part of HTML file (only the responsible JavaScript (Ajax function))

```
function mentor() {
  // 1. Create XHR instance - Start
  var oblast = document.getElementById("oblast").value; //previous dropdown from which I need to create next one
  document.getElementById("mentorr").innerHTML = ""; //emtpy the dropdown I need to create 

  instancee();
  // 1. Create XHR instance - End

  // 2. Define what to do when XHR feed you the response from the server - Start
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
        var val = xhr.responseText; 
        alert(val); //just a check to see does it get correct data, and it get, everything is OK so far

        var jsonData = JSON.parse(val);
        var selectList = document.getElementById('mentorr'); //id of the dropdown I need to create

        for (var i in jsonData) {
          var option = document.createElement('option');
          //$response[$i]['name'];
          option.value = jsonData['id'][i];
          option.text = jsonData['name'][i];
          selectList.appendChild(option);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // 2. Define what to do when XHR feed you the response from the server - Start

  // 3. Specify your action, location and Send to the server - Start 
  xhr.open('POST', 'ajax.php');

  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.send("oblast=" + oblast);
}
```

Part of ajax.php file that fetches data and sends to HTML:

```
$queryData1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profesori WHERE idprof = '$prof'");

while($result2 = mysql_fetch_array($queryData1)) {
  $id=$result2['idprof'];
  $profesor=$result2['ime']. " ".$result2['prezime'];

  $data = array
  (
    'id' => array($id),
    'name' => array($profesor)
  );

  echo json_encode($data);      
}
```

`alert(var)` line of code gives this:

[image]

So data is corretly fetched from database and sent to HTML. But the problem is in populating dropdown menu (parsing data). Error in console in "unexpected token {" in the line

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(val);
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You could call val.toString() and check whether its really a JSON.

Comment: `JSON.parse('{"id":["2"],"name":["Zdravko Topic"]}')` works fine, although you do not need to cast `array` in your php code.

Comment: It is really JSON.. I cant parse like that because value wont be "id":["2"],"name":["Zdravko Topic"] always, question is how to parse multidimensional array with values ('id' => $varid, 'name'=> $varname) and put that into dropdown like <option value="$varid"> $varname </option>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = jsonData[i].id;
    option.text = jsonData[i].name;
    selectList.appendChild(option);
}
```

Should do the trick, JSON.parse returns json objects, you can loop through the objects using an index and fetch properties of an object like this "object.property".

Comment: looks promisinig (50% of answer). But still cannot JSON.parse 2d array.. I am getting unexpected token { error at:  var jsonData = JSON.parse(val);

Comment: The json parses just fine for me, also you're storing both the id and the name as an individual array, try to store it as 'id' => $id and 'name' => $professor in ajax.php

Comment: I have corrected array in ajax.php as you said...And fixed JSON.parse, however JSON.parse only work when I have only one database query like {"id":["2"],"name":["Zdravko Topic"]}, when i have multiple queries like : {"id":["1"],"name":["Name Lastname"]}{"id":["2"],"name":["Zdravko Topic"]}, then it gives me unexpected token again. Could you try on that example? Oh and yeah, jsonData.length doesnt work at all, it says undefined.. When I use only one database query like: {"id":["2"],"name":["Zdravko Topic"]} without for loop, then it works like charm,,, litlle bit confusing,eh

Comment: Got it,, your code is good... I was creating not valid JSON in my php script